# ユーザー情報ごとに、表示する画像を変えたい

Tags: python, django

ユーザー情報ごとに、表示する画像を変えたいです。
現在、住んでいる地域ごとに表示する画像を変えるシステムを作っています。
models.pyに

```
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sex = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class BackgroundImages(models.Model):
　  city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True,)
```

と書きました。データベースのUserテーブルには、

```
user_id | age | sex | city
1         24     0     NY
2         50     1     CF
3         32     1     LD
```

のように入っていて、
BackgroundImagesテーブルには、

```
city | image 
NY      newyork1.png
CF      california1.png
LD      london1.png
NY      newyork2.png
CF      california2.png
LD      london2.png
```

のように画像データが入っています。
views.pyには

```
@login_required
    def select_img(request):
        back_image = BackgroundImages.objects.all().filter(#ユーザーの住んでいる地域を入れる)
        return render(request, 'top.html', {'back_image': back_image})
```

と書きました。ユーザーにはログインをしてもらっているのでユーザーデータは一意に決まると思っています。しかし、この`#ユーザーの住んでいる地域を入れる`の所に、どのようにUserモデルのcityを取り出すコードを書けるかわかりません。この場合、どのようにコードを書けるかご存知でしたら教えてください。